# Clicking on Html.ActionLink refreshing the layout view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 3 project created from the default template in Visual Studio. In that project in the layout view i added  a dropdownlist using a view and Html.Action like

In _Layout.cshtml

```
 @Html.Action("Index", "DdlDept")
```

In Index.cshtml of DdlDeptController.cs

```
@model PassingValuesInViews.Models.DdlDeptViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDeptId, new SelectList(Model.Depts, "Id" , "DeptName"))
```

When i run the project and click on one of the default links to the home controller

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

The page is refreshed and whatever i selected in the dropdownbox is cleared and the default valued is selected again.

Why does the DropDownBox refesh , how do i prevent that.

My objective is to have a common dropdown box for a couple of views.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.ActionLink will always refresh the page.  It is the same action that would occur if you clicked on a link generated by traditional  tags.

If you needed something to reload a small section, you're looking for an ajax call via @Ajax.ActionLink.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Home", // <-- Text to display
     "Index", // <-- Action Method Name
     new AjaxOptions
     {
         UpdateTargetId="CustomerList", // <-- DOM element ID to update
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, // <-- Replace the content of DOM element
         HttpMethod = "GET" // <-- HTTP method

     })
```

Sample taken from the following tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/

Comment: Hi David, I tried using your method but the selected value of the dropdown is still refreshed, is there anything else i can try.

Comment: @Prakash Was the entire page refreshing or just the dropdown?

Comment: Looking more into it , i realised that the only the dropdown is refreshing. I think its because im using html.action to render it. How can i make the dropbox retain its state. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not sure what is triggering the state change.  What seems to drive the change?

Comment: put the dropdown outside the area that is refreshed via ajax avtionlink\